# img swap not working on SAFARI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I face a problem with Safari, that I do not face with google chrome or firefox...
I am switching the image with jQuery between the src attribute of a image, and the other-src attribute.
On Chrome and FireFox, this works perfectly fine, but on Safari the image become tiny or even disappear after a mouse out...
Here is the code :

```
<img src="a.svg" class='menuOptions' other-src="b.svg" />
function changeImg(div){
   div.find('.menuOptionsImg').attr({
       src : div.find('.menuOptionsImg').attr('other-src')
       , 'other-src' : div.find('.menuOptionsImg').attr('src')
   })
}
```

Any workaround?

Many thanks to you guys !

Comment: my guess is that Safari might not support non-standard attributes such as `other-src`. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW1

Comment: It does because I can see the image changing, but it become tiny, or sometimes disappear, but I can see from the code that se src changes !

Comment: Is there some reason you're using an other-src attribute? You should use the browser-supported data attribute -  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: @user3389396 I see. Have you tried setting the `width` and `height` attributes as well? This might resolve the problem.